# How to ignore declared temp table columns in select query where all field has NULL value for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to ignore columns where all column value is null from select query from declared temp table.

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (
    [RowID] INT not null primary key identity(1, 1),        
    [ID] BIGINT,
    [Column1] BIGINT,
    [Column2] CHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO @TempTable (ID, Column1, column2) VALUES (1, NULL, NULL) ;
INSERT INTO @TempTable (ID, Column1, column2) VALUES (2, NULL, NULL) ;
INSERT INTO @TempTable (ID, Column1, column2) VALUES (3, NULL, NULL) ;
INSERT INTO @TempTable (ID, Column1, column2) VALUES (4, NULL, NULL) ;

SELECT * FROM @TempTable
```

Here in select query i want to ignore Column1 and Column2 as the value is null for all rows.

Or another way to say 
"How to retrieve only columns which having at least one not null value in any row."

I found a link below but it is not helping much.

[How to retreive only columns which having at least one not null value in any row.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/98fdf8cc-80b9-4951-8d00-70957605a689/how-to-retreive-only-columns-which-having-at-least-one-not-null-value-in-any-row?forum=transactsql)

Comment: add your query please

Comment: There's only one way to ignore a row where all the values have the value *`NULL`*, using a `WHERE`: `WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col2 IS NOT NULL AND Col3 IS NOT NULL AND... Col100 IS NOT NULL...`. You get the idea. A better question, in all honesty, is *why* do you have rows filled with *`NULL`*? The row is utterly meaningless. I'd suggest cleaning your source data, rather than trying to fitler it out. You also need to post a much better question (in fact, you need to ask a question, they end with a  question mark(`?`)). [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @B3S I updated query

Comment: Your question is still not clear my friend. If you just want to ignore some columns, dont use `select *`. Put your wanted output only, like: `SELECT ID`. If you dont want records which have `NULL` in column 1 or column 2 (or both) you should add this in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @larnu those null column comes up after PIVOT data from a table (that is expected). But to display in report tool, i need to ignore all columns from select query for a temp declared table where column value is NULL.

Comment: now i got the point i guess. im goint to post an answer

Comment: @B3S, as i am getting data after doing PIVOT, so i am not sure which column has null value for all rows. So i need to figure it out.

Comment: When you say you want to "ignore" `Column1` and `Column2`, are you saying you don't want to output them in your resultset? If so, you'll only be able to do that with Dynamic-SQL; as "normal"SQL will always have the same resultset definition. Expected results would be helpful.

Comment: Yes I don't want output them in my resultset. Another point is i am using declared table. So if i want to use dynamic query how i will get data from  declated temp table?

Comment: Why are you using a variable over a temporary table? Table Variables are (generally) worse. (Also, calling it `@TempTable` is miss leading, as it is **not** a Temp(orary) Table).

Comment: @Larnu then i need to ask question "Why table variable is worse?". Should i use temp table instead of table variable?

Comment: The biggest problem is they produce extremely poor query plans. When selecting from a Table Variable, the estimated number of rows returns will be **1**, regardless of how many rows you inserted. On the other hand, a Temporary Table will least give a more realistic number. A estimate of 1 can cause massive problems, as this (very likely) means that the estimate for the rest of the plan will be wrong, resulting in poor query performance and high spill to tempdb. Yes, a Temporary Table is stored in tempdb as well, however, smaller tables will still be used in RAM, not the HDD/SSD/etc.

Comment: I *beleive* in a later version of SQL Server (2016 or 2017) they changed the estimate on Table Variables, but (iirc) they only changed it from 1 to 100; that doesn't really help unless you really are putting exactly 100 rows in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with dynamic sql. Build your COLUMNS list based on case statement (counting nulls), then add it to your query
   EDIT: a #TempTable instead of @TempTable would be better.

```
create table #TempTable (
[RowID] INT not null primary key identity(1, 1), 

[ID] BIGINT,
[Column1] BIGINT,
[Column2] CHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID, Column1, column2) VALUES (1, 1, NULL) ;
INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID, Column1, column2) VALUES (2, NULL, NULL) ;
INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID, Column1, column2) VALUES (3, NULL, NULL) ;
INSERT INTO #TempTable (ID, Column1, column2) VALUES (4, NULL, NULL) ;

DECLARE @COLUMNS nVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @COLUMNS = 'ID'+ CASE WHEN 
                        (SELECT COUNT(ID) COL_NULLS FROM #TempTable WHERE Column1 IS NOT NULL) > 0
                    THEN ',Column1' ELSE '' END +
                    CASE WHEN 
                        (SELECT COUNT(ID) COL_NULLS FROM #TempTable WHERE Column2 IS NOT NULL) > 0
                    THEN ',Column2' ELSE '' END
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT '+@COLUMNS+' FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the idea. But one problem that is my data is in a declared temp table. So how i wil pass that data into dynamic query? Insted of declred table should i use #temp table?

Comment: Yes. of course. And i edited my answer in order to accomplish that.

Comment: You're welcome. Please dont forget to accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic approach:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = '#YourTableName'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ValidColumns') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ValidColumns

CREATE TABLE #ValidColumns (ColumnName VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE ColumnCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        QUOTENAME(C.Name)
    FROM
        tempdb.sys.columns AS C
    WHERE
        C.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..' + @TableName)

OPEN ColumnCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @ColumnName

DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @DynamicSQL = '
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + @TableName + ' AS T WHERE T.' + @ColumnName + ' IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #ValidColumns (ColumnName) VALUES (''' + @ColumnName + ''')
        END
    '

    EXEC (@DynamicSQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @ColumnName

END

CLOSE ColumnCursor
DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor

DECLARE @SelectColumnList VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT
            ',' + C.ColumnName
        FROM
            #ValidColumns AS C
        FOR XML
            PATH ('')
    ),
    1, 1, '')

SET @DynamicSQL = 'SELECT ' + @SelectColumnList + ' FROM ' + @TableName

EXEC (@DynamicSQL)
```

It's a little bit messy but it's the only way to handle a dynamic temporal table name with multiple columns.